# Where do the files downloaded/created in persistent mode get stored?

Tags: live-usb

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 from my usb drive in persistence mode. I haven't installed it.
Where do the apps downloaded or files created in libre office get stored? On the pen drive itself?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

They are indeed installed on the pendrive. The casper-rw file resides on the pen drive's file system. From what I have seen it is usually an MS FAT file system of some kind. The casper-rw file, itself, is a block of disk space, formatted as a Linux EXT file system--so it's a file system within a file system. To see inside when you aren't running Ubuntu from the pen drive you have to set up a loopback device and then mount it.

```
casper-rw file -> loopback device -> mounted file system of changed and new files
```

casper-rw is mounted in a way that when you read a file, if it is on casper-rw you read it, if not you read it from the read-only files on the pen drive. If you write to the boot drive while it's booted, the file is written the the casper-rw file system. Therefore the casper-rw file system contains only new or changed files.

Unless you set up the loopback device and mount it you can't see the files you have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are stored on the pendrive itself. I'm not sure in which directories are the files stored, but you can always use the `find` command.

See the man page of `find` command, it is a very powerful command, and can be confusing at first. As a simple example, to search for a file named `newfile.txt` in `/home/user/abc' the following command can be used:

```
find /home/user/abc -iname "newfile.txt"
```

Note that `find` can take quite a time to complete the search, therefore it is preferred that you narrow down the path, where you want to search for, as much as possible.